# functions covered under imported library

Tags: python, machine-learning, import, anaconda

I have imported numpy library in my python code. Now my question is, is it possible to get a list of all the functions that are covered under the numpy library? I know documentation is a thing, but I am looking for something else. 
I use spyder.

Answer (score 0):

### print(dir(numpy))

The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information:

- If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the
  module’s attributes.
- If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names
  of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.
- Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the
  names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of
  its class’s base classes.

Comment: invalid syntax. I am using python 3.6.4

Comment: print(dir(numpy))

Comment: cool. This gets me what I asked. But, can I have the attributes of the function and the overview about what is happening in the function?

Comment: i would suggest documentation

Answer (score 0):

one trick you can use is that, in spyder's IPython console window, type this"

```
np.__all__
```

And this can list all the method names.
FYI, in ipython or jupyter notebook, library has hidden attributs like "**all**", "**file**",etc, which you could check by using TAB after typing library name.